# 2 column float wasted space

Tags: css, css-float

I have a container `div`, inside which I want to pack a variable number of `div`s of unknown (variable) height but with a given `min-width`. My requirements are:

1. If the container is wide enough to accommodate two columns, I want them to distribute themselves nicely in two columns without unnecessary whitespace.
2. It not, they should just go above each other.

Currently, I've given the `div`s `width:48% margin-right:2%;float:left;` which works nicely in the one-column state but when I resize the browser window, making room for two columns, every `div` which ends up in the left column insists on aligning itself horizontally with the bottom of the last `div` which went to the right:

[what I have http://img602.imageshack.us/img602/5719/whatihave.png](http://img602.imageshack.us/img602/5719/whatihave.png)

This is how I would like them to go (no wasted space):

[what I want http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6985/whatiwantu.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6985/whatiwantu.png)

I would like a pure CSS solution if possible.

Thank you! /Gustav

EDIT:
This markup illustrates my problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
  width: 48%;
  min-width:550px;
  margin-right:2%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  height:180px;
  float:left;
}

.tall {
  height: 250px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box tall">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div style="clear:both"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.box`es are generated dynamically, and so are their heights, I just threw in one taller to illustrate.

Comment: If you want a pure CSS solution, maybe you should post your markup and CSS instead of screen snaps.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is .odd-box{float:left;} .even-box{float:right;} but the problem there is if the container is wider than the .box divs then you get a scattered layout. Kinda just hoping this sparks some ideas maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve the desired effect with pure CSS. I've used [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) to replicate the effect you're after and it worked really well.

I'd love to see a pure CSS solution for this but haven't seen anything come close yet.

Comment: This was, in a way, the kind of answer I was hoping for. (And fearing, of course). The third sentence on the the page states it explicitly: "Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then vertically". Looks awesome though, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you have a div for each column into which you put the numbered divs you will get what you want.  Something like this:

```
<div class="containerDiv">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The next step appears to be "how do I balance my columns".  Some code somewhere is generating the boxes you mentioned.  It is deciding on the height of each box.  This code will need to generate a balanced list of boxes for each column prior to forwarding the request to the JSP for presentation.  By balanced, I mean "the height of column1 is similar to the height to column2"

Comment: I found that approach difficult since I don't know up front how tall each `.content` will be and thus can't know which `column` to append it to. Or rather, the "next" one... Furthermore (assuming that the `columns` are floated), the ordering will be weird when "collapsing" to one column.